# ¿Cómo integrar mi aplicación Android con Google Play Games?

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

He creado una aplicación donde se registra una variable que es el número de toques que das a un botón, y lo quiero hacer online. He buscado en muchos sitios pero espero que me brindéis aquí con alguna solución, alguno? Lo he programado en Eclipse y está en Google Play y todo, sólo me hace falta qué poner dentro o qué hacer para hacer que aparezca online, es decir, en Google Play Games no?

Comment: Hare una serie de preguntas, 1 -la aplicacion esta hecha, 2 - esta publicada en Google Play, 3 - Quieres integracion con Google Play Games, responde en ese mismo orden, con si o no

Comment: Sí, Sí, sí , creo que está claro arriba , lo que pregunto es si online debe ser sí o sí Play Games y si es así, consejos para ver cómo lo hago, Pedro ;)

Comment: bueno, asumo que lo que buscas es esto [gpg1](https://developers.google.com/games/services/) y [gpg2](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart), mas no se si ya habias visto eso

Comment: Con eso podré sí o sí conseguir incorporarlo a google play games con sus clasficaciones y todo, como cualquier app que está puesta ahí? Por cierto, es fácil lograrlo?

Comment: Pues la verdad no se si lo sea, ya que nunca lo he hecho, mas bien deberias reformular tu pregunta, a algo asi, Como integrar mi aplicacion android con Google Play Game

Comment: ya está editado, gracias ;)

Comment: Ok, esperemos para ver si te responden, si no pues podrias hacer la pregunta en SOen, pero si no hablas ingles pues usa un traductor

Comment: Sigue esta guia origina y podras subirla al play store https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=es-419

Comment: si ya la tienes acabada y subida pero los demás no la ven, lo que te falta es firmar para autenticar i clasificar la aplicación, ya que al compartirla publicamente, google play te debe identificar: [aqui instrucciones con eclipse](http://www.galisteocantero.com/firmar-y-alinear-aplicacion-android-desde-eclipse/) y [aquí para hacerlo sin ningun IDE](http://jonsegador.com/2014/11/firmar-aplicacion-android-sin-utilizar-eclipse-android-studio/). Hace tiempo que no subo nada al market, pero si no recuerdo mal y no ha cambiado, debes registrarte como developer y tiene coste (unos 25$)

Comment: Está subida y se puede descargar y todo, lo que quiero es subirla para que jueguen y haya una leaderboard y se puede jugar online...

Answer (score 3):

Lee la **[guía oficial de Google para publicar tu aplicación.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=es-419)** , pero te muestro un tutorial básico de como realizarlo.

Primeramente tienes que entrar a la [consola de desarrollo Google Play](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/):

https://play.google.com/apps/publish/

simplemente agrega tu .apk y realiza su publicación, Ve a la sección `All Applications` -> `APK` y mediante el botón `"Upload new APK to Production"` puedes cargar tu aplicación :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

obviamente tu cuenta con la que estas autenticado debe haber pagado por el programa de desarrollo.

Para que te permita publicar tu aplicación tienes que llenar los requisitos de la sección `Store Listing`.

Es importante asegurar que tu aplicación sea soportada en los dispositivos, al menos en los que deseas sea compatible, en ocasiones no aparece porque no esta soportada en algunos dispositivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando tengas lista tu aplicación simplemente Publicala mediante el botón `"Move to Prod"`!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]